# Display details of a node in a workflow with converging nodes

Tags: workflow, graphs, nodes

I'm making a workflow editor where each node in a DAG can have multiple inputs, multiple outputs and it can be called multiple times in a single execution.

[image: workflow editor]

My next task is creating a display that will show details of the execution. I've made it so that clicking on a node opens up a panel that shows details where one can select in a dropdown for what input, from which node's output Nº a message is coming from.

[image]

for Divide by 10 node the select dropdown would contain: ***Into INPUT from Multiply by 2 OUTPUT #1***

It looks a bit raw and cumbersome to select that way. Is there a more intuitive way to show that a message has flowed through the node and to be able to get to the node details easily?

Comment: Have you looked at this question about graph based user interfaces for some ideas? https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/148705/components-in-graph-based-ui-with-more-complex-interactions